# Why do some ScriptResource.axd calls succeed and others fail?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

We have a website that runs on ASP.NET 4.

I notice the website renders two ScriptResource.axd requests. On our QA environment the one request succeeds and the other request fails (with a 404 error). On all other environments both calls succeed.

The request urls are...

- This one works:
  http://qa.www.fin24.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=EXDGAyD7E-g0TI3ln2UV0Ito6mFPfvKoqGrtHwYwGdVJJOUwJ8gsPer-44iuksfoAzBnFSzXOLvF2P_wqjS6qmSsyI9GhZdZOUN3O0Z5p9JsE-pk_3BD4OQnX_Kud_dHKag4ecuNm9c042HsChtnGRiQU9rGs-ZiZBSlMUWBm6afRr20thS8CZ6ecsS-LuSV0&t=2610f696
- This one returns a 404:
  http://qa.www.fin24.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=PxoN2ObK88-8ae9bfqlj3V1AtnVv55YrZDDzgP3QS3cLonT7ilIgG1Ealrod7pi8hllo--dMwM5l9a_Gg8llygZZn50tZRKvfuDReuNGwaBszxD6QDss_qeT81nleD9XNVL7XI6RlZHHk2ktLrnLqcBNnZNBvUG2IYldG5UG-71Rj6CH9HYLfidCe6mJeX2M0&t=2610f696

Why would the second one fail?

I've read that these calls relate to different DLLs, so I'm guessing one DLL is not on the server? But I don't know which DLLs.

Am I on the right track? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must have been a problem with ASP.NET. I deleted the website in IIS and re-created it.

Problem solved!